# Happens-before guarantee of Executor.submit()

Tags: java, java-memory-model, happens-before

[Javadoc of Executor interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) says the following:

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to submitting a `Runnable` object to an `Executor` happen-before its execution begins, perhaps in another thread.

Which part of the Java Language Specification guarantees that? Or is it only because the implementations use some internal synchronization? (An example would be great if that's the case.) So when implementing a custom `Executor` should I be aware of this requirement?

Comment: Well, the javadoc specifies it. The JLS doesn't specify the API. It specifies the language. And yes, if you were to implement an Executor, you'd better comply with the specifications of the Executor interface.

Comment: Well, in general the language does guarantee that code that is thread-confined executes in a sequential fashion.  It wouldn't be possible to establish any happens-before relationship otherwise at all in single-threaded applications.  Therefore, the statement above doesn't require any specification by the memory model (which deals with visibility and consistency of mutable data between threads).  The above is merely reinforcing the notion that the code leading up to the submission will have executed before the submission begins executing (even if in another thread).

Comment: @scottb I disagree. If, for example, the worker thread continuously polled an ArrayList for a new task, you wouldn't have any happens-before guarantee: the worker thread could see a new item in the list, but in an inconsistent state. So care must be taken by the executor to provide that guarantee (synchronization, etc.)

Comment: @JBNizet: Well, yes of course.  But then code which is executing in a worker thread is not exactly thread confined, is it.

Comment: I don't see how thread-confinement is relevant to the question: the OP is asking about submitting, from thread A, a task to an Executor, that will execute it in thread B. The executor must take care that the submission happens-before the execution of the task. That doesn't happen by itself. Synchronization is needed (wait/notify, volatile write/read, whatever).

Comment: @JBNizet - Your comments should be an Answer ... :-)

Comment: @StephenC alright. Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JLS doesn't specify the API. It specifies the language. The javadoc is the API specification.

And thus yes, if you were to implement an Executor, you'd better comply with the specifications of the Executor interface. The executor must take care that the submission *happens-before* the execution of the task. That doesn't happen by itself. Synchronization is needed (wait/notify, volatile write/read, etc.).